# Using CLISP and recursion

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

create a list or an array of random integers (e.g., between [0, 50]) and a target number (e.g., 60), then find all subsets of the integers of the list/array such that the numbers in each subsets add up to the target number. Print the numbers of each subset, you also need to print the original indices of the numbers. For example, given array A = {5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7}, target = 9, the number pairs are (5, 4), (3, 6), (2, 7), and (3, 4, 2). Their indices are (0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5), and (1, 2, 3), respectively. (Optional) If you implement the programs using both array and list, compare the difference between sorting array and sorting list in Lisp.

Comment: That's a great task. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously you are missing a clear question here. I would consider that you think about what SO is meant to be and how others can participate the most from your questions and the given answers.

Nevertheless, while you are thinking about the problem you could start with something like this:

```
(defun random-list (&optional (len 10) (limit 50))
  "Returns a list of length LEN with random integers upto LIMIT."
  (loop :for n :from 1 :upto len
        :collect (1+ (random limit))))
```

Another way would be to implement it as a recursive function. There are great online resources given in the info section of the CL tag.

If you are facing difficulties while implementing the complete tasks, I am sure you will find help here.